# Need help with calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-list

I need column1 to determine the value of column2.

So If column1 equals yes column2 needs to equal yes;

and

If column1 equals no then column2 should equal no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as

```
=Column1
```

Since you said if column1 = yes the column2 = yes

If you are looking for more logic.. then the conditional logic goes as

```
=if(column1="Yes", "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: Also see: http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions